# Broken pipe error when restoring data to the database

Tags: postgresql

Why do I get a broken pipe error in postgresql when restoring a database?

```
cat test_qa_201501221645_IST.sql.gz|gunzip|psql -d sample_qa_new
```

Where `test_qa_201501221645_IST.sql.gz` is the file name, and 
`sample_qa_new` is the database name.

Answer (score 0):

you get a broken pipe error because gunzip or psql has exited before the input was fully consumed.

The errors immediately before "broken pipe" may give some clue as to what happened.  if not check syslog, dmesg, etc...